# Customizable alternative to static_assert in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compile-time

I'm working with some code that uses elaborate template metaprogramming to "assert" on variable equalities/inequalities at compile-time, hacking the compiler's error messages to display the values seen by the compiler on each side of the test.

So for a simplified, not-NDA-breaking example, you might have:

```
template<bool>
struct test
{

};

template<>
struct test<true>
{
    using result = char;
};

template<int x, int y>
struct CheckEqual
{
   typedef typename test<x == y>::result result;
}

CheckEqual<sizeof(int), sizeof(char)>::result equality; // Example assertion declaration
```

This example will print out a complicated error message, and somewhere in there will be the template declaration seen by the compiler, `test<4, 1>`.

My goal is to make this more readable, since "[result] is not a member of test<number, number>" isn't too easy to associate with specific files/callsites. I've tried replacing the tests with `static_assert` invocations, and the suggestion was knocked back because the compiled values of `x` and `y` would stop showing up in the output.

Afterwards I attempted to do something clever with character parameter-packs, `constexpr` and `static_assert`, hoping that I could construct a readable error message that included the compiled values of each argument. That failed when I realized that `static_assert` *only* takes string literals.

What I'm thinking now is that Visual Studio has `#error` for pre-processor messages and `OutputDebugStringW/A` for runtime messages, so it must have some sort of compiler extension for output during compilation - I'm wondering if anyone knows what might be. What I would love is something that behaves like `static_assert`, but allows for variable as well as literal output.

My goal is to emit an error and output a string at compile time reading "Assertion failed; [x] ([compiled value of x]) != [y] ([compiled value of y])".

I'm aware a VS-specific extension will be non-portable, but for now I'm not really concerned - so long as this works on some PCs, its better than nothing. Future versions can use extensions for GCC, clang, etc.

Comment: Try something like `template<int x, int y, bool = true> struct CheckEqual {};` `template<int x, int y> struct CheckEqual<x, y, x == y> {using result = char;};` and then at least it should tell you `result` is not a member of `CheckEqual<4,1>` and it should point to the line where you used CheckEqual?

Comment: I believe, there is no such portable solution. `static_assert` needs string literal ( p. 156, [dcl.pre] https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf). But you can write your own macro for comparison: https://godbolt.org/z/7ja7jM7Ys .

Comment: @user253751 I don't believe that's valid syntax? Its a recursive definition, so intellisense gives "the template argument list of the partial specialization includes a nontype argument whose type depends on a template parameter" (= the template can't be resolved because its parameters depend on each other).

Comment: @trokymchuk that was the original alternative I suggested ^_^'. It's my preference as well, but people are dumb and want something that keeps using all the template machinery.

Comment: @Kate it's a template specialization, and `bool = true` is an unnamed default argument. It specializes `CheckEqual<1, 1, true>` and `CheckEqual<1, 2, false>` and so on. So `CheckEqual<1,1>` is the specialization and `CheckEqual<1,2>` is not.